# How to stop "No video with supported format and mime found" box before a .WEBM shows?

Tags: wordpress, webm

I have a .webm file that displays near the top on the desktop version of my website [here](https://www.h2xengineering.com).

This is an example or what it looks like

[image]

For a quick second as you reload the page, you see a black box with the message "No video with supported format and MIME found" before the .webm file proceeds to load. You can see what I mean here:

This is what you see quickly on a reload

[image]

Is this a normal thing to happen with .webm files on Wordpress websites or is there a way to fix this so it doesn't display?

Comment: Look at your browser console log and Network tab, then [edit] your question and tell us what you see there. It's possible some client-side Javascript is trying to load a .mp4 file first.  Or, better yet, convert your .webm file to a .mp4 file and use that. It will work in Safari where .webm won't.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to fix it now. For some reason my theme was loading a .mp4 version of it.